# What if I don't have the feedback service from APNS (Apple push notification Server) running?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Long story, but what if my feedback service on my server isn't running? The port is open but I don't do anything with it.

Everything seems to work fine, i.e. our users get push notifications. But there is a feeling within the development team that, if the feedback service isn't installed, Apple will get annoyed and stop push notification.

Is there anything in that?

(There are reasons for not having it running which are beyond the scope of this question.)

Many thanks!

Andy

Answer (score 2):

There may by repercussions for not using the Feedback Service, as implied [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3):

> APNs monitors providers for their diligence in checking the feedback service and refraining from sending push notifications to nonexistent applications on devices.

You don't have to connect to the feedback service from your production server, if you have reasons not to do so. You can connect to it from a development computer. Later you'll have to process the returned device tokens, and remove them from your production DB. You can do it (for example) once a day.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It sounds like we might be able to 'get away with' not having the feedback service running for a few days. Our app is very niche, only has around 20 users right now and that won't grow very much during the next 2 weeks...

Comment: I contacted Apple. The person I spoke to didn't know, but he passed it on to the next level of supoort, and suggested it would be a few days before I got a response. Nothing yet, which suggests that it won't be fatal!